# Custom view class on top of an Activity

Tags: android

I have an Activity.There is native java Unity view. And then webview on top of it to show the HTML. So This Activity has Unity and HTML view stacked on top of each other. Here is the activity below:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);

    context = this;

    if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
        getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
    setContentView(playerView);
    playerView.requestFocus();

    mJSInterface = new JSInterface();        

    Log.e("Cookie", "COOKIE SUPPORT!");

        mWebView = new WebView(this);



        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
        addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.addView(mWebView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY));
        // Basic settings of WebView.

        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);



        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});


       /* mJSInterface = new JSInterface();
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mJSInterface, "UnityInterface");*/


        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mJSInterface, "UnityInterface");

        // Start in invisible state.
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}
```

Also I have a custom view class. I want to set this class on top of this activity. Here is my View Class:

```
public class PrintView extends LinearLayout {

    WebView wv;

    public PrintView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.printscreen, this);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPrint);
        wv.loadUrl(Constant.printUrl);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
            getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }


}
```

In my activity there is a method "loadPrintActivity". I want the view class on top of the Activity, when this method is called. Here is the method:

```
    public void loadPrintActivity(String printUrl) {
    PrintView pv = new PrintView(context);
    setContentView(pv);
}
```

I used it. But it's not working. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you start another Activity like this:

```
    public void loadPrintActivity(String printUrl) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

From within the Activity that is currently in foreground. Android then maintains a stack of Activities, if the user presses the "back" button he will get back to the prvious Activity. You can react on all that in Activities `onResume` and `onPause`.

For more information, take a look at Android's [Guide about back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Comment: @jobi, thx for your answer. But i want to set my view class on top of my activity class, not activity.

Comment: So you want to replace all currently shown view with a new view/layout?

Comment: I want to put my view class "PrintView "  on top of my activity. Printview is not an Activity it's a view.

Comment: Well, exactly that is the issue you have. In Android instead of replacing views inside an Sctivity, you create a new Activity, start that and give the new Activity your `PrintView` as content. If you dont want the user to get back to the calling Activity by pressing the back key, then you set the corresponding 'replace' flag in the Intent. That's Adnroid, dont blame me :-)